# Packaging .m libraries into MATLAB executables

Tags: linux, matlab

I feel like this is a relatively basic question, but a solution seems to be beyond my Google-fu.

## Setup:

I have a matlab project in ~/project which references a matlab library (cplex) in a folder /s/cplex/matlab. I can successfully compile my application by calling addpath('/s/cplex/matlab') and then running my main() script.

## Goal:

I want to build my project as an executable so that it still can reference /s/cplex/matlab. Ideally, /s/cplex/matlab will be packaged into this executable so that it is portable.

## Problem:

My attempts at making this work have all been futile. I've pored through http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/ and tried:

1. Add /s/cplex/cplex/matlab to LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the executable
2. Add /s/cplex/cplex/matlab to LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting MATLAB so that it is on the MATLAB LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. Add /s/cplex/cplex/matlab to the Shared Resources and Helper Files panel in MATLAB's deploytool
4. Add /s/cplex/cplex/matlab to the MATLAB path via addpath() before compiling
5. Add /s/cplex/cplex/matlab to the Package panel in MATLAB's deploytool

Through all of these attempts, the resulting executable could still not locate the cplex directory. What is the best way to link/package a matlab executable to its .m dependencies?

Comment: What kind of files are in /s/cplex/matlab and how do you call them?

Comment: /s/cplex/matlab contains the matlab wrapper files for cplex (located in /s/cplex/bin). I first call Cplex('bilp') and then solve an LP problem using the API described here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2FContent%2FOptimization%2FDocumentation%2FCPLEX%2F_pubskel%2FCPLEX1133.html .

Comment: Are you getting some error related to not finding cplex libraries? Could the API functions be using relative paths to locate the libraries. Does the API use mex files linked against the libraries? If the API got compiled into your app then relative paths would not work correctly.

Comment: Yes. When I run the program from within Matlab (after calling addpath('/s/cplex/matlab'), it runs fine. But when I run the executable after compiling, I get the error Undefined function 'Cplex' for input arguments of type 'char'. This error is in the function calling the API, not from the API itself, so I take this to mean that the problem is in my program not finding the API, not in the API not finding mex files. Really, my question is just how to package a set of .m files not on the main project path into a deployed executable.

Comment: Two things to try. In command line mcc you can include -C option to generate a separate CTF archive. You can inspect this file using "unzip" and check whether your files are packed. Another option is to manually add the API files when running mcc just to see whether that fixes your issue. Ideally compiler would pick up these files automatically.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that: I did a few experiments with the CTF archives and found: When I didn't explicitly link in the API directory, cplex did not show up at all in the final CTF. When I did explicitly add them in, they did show up under the fully resolved path, i.e. /prefixes/s/cplex-12.5/%40sys/cplex/matlab/%40Cplex. I wonder if the '@' characters resolving to '%40' could be causing a problem because part of the error message was "A class definition must be in an "@" directory." Cplex is called as a class, so I wonder if that could be the reason MCR isn't finding it.

Comment: I do not know why you are getting this error. Sorry.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for sticking it out with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahah! Fixed it.

## Problem

To anyone who had a similar problem, the problem was indeed with the @ symbols. I was using the AFS file system, which resolves @sys in a filepath to the machine/operating system pair. There there were '@sys' strings in my paths to keep it general-purpose, which MATLAB saw and misread as the keyword to denote a class folder.

## Solution

I replaced all occurrences of '@sys' with the actual folder name, and MATLAB parsed them correctly. Note that this solution was not immediately obvious because the path I was using was a symbolic link to the full path with the '@sys' strings.